# Having issues changing the settings in my Materials Tab in Blender 2.8

Tags: texturing, materials

I've been trying to figure out how to change these settings back to what I had originally which allowed me to create a Displacement and Bump on my models. However, this menu keeps popping up and I've never seen it before.

Could anyone give me some advice to change this?
Settings down below are the settings I'm trying to get that has the Surface Setting in the Material Setting.

[image: Different Material Settings]

[image]

Comment: You don't need to worry about that. Try using the node editor, as once you get used to it, you can't/don't want to use anything else for shading.

Comment: Though the thing is, I want to use the displacement settings like I did with my previous work as I found that to be easier and I just want to know in future where I went wrong

Comment: Since you are unfamiliar with these settings, could it be that you intended to use Cycles instead of Eevee?

Comment: I'll give that a shot, It could be because I didn't change the Eevee Render to Cycles